# Creating a Doughnut chart using JSON and chart.js

Tags: jquery, json, chart.js

this is the first time I am playing with chart.js for analytics purpose. I have been googling around for a full solution on how to pass JSON data from SQL Database using LINQ Lambda expression into chart.js on a .NET platform. However I could not find a good tutorial on that.

- **Background**

I wanted to make a doughnut chart that passed JSON data. However, I encountered some hip cups with my Doughnut chart. It did not appear. My bar, stack chart are all working with the same format except my Doughnut chart. My doughnut should be able to accept data from a relational table using LINQ.  Below is my code.

```
 $(window).load(function () {
                 //window.onload = function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "Dashboard.aspx/getPieChartData",
                     data: "{}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (msg) {
                         var aData = msg.d;

                         var aLabels = aData[0];
                         var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
                         var aDatasets2 = aData[2];
                         var aDatasets3 = aData[3];

                         var options2 = {
                              showScale: false,
                              scaleShowGridLines: false,
                              scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
                               scaleGridLineWidth: 0,
                               scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
                              scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
                              bezierCurve: false,
                            <%-- multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>",--%>
                             bezierCurveTension: 0.4,
                            pointDot: false,
                            pointDotRadius: 0,
                            pointDotStrokeWidth: 2,
                            pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
                             datasetStroke: true,
                           datasetStrokeWidth: 4,
                           datasetFill: true,

                         };


                         var barChartData = {
                             labels: aLabels,
                             datasets: [

                            {
                                value: aDatasets1,
                                color: "#00c396",
                                highlight: "#00c396"
                                 //label: "Batch"
                             }, {
                                 value: aDatasets2,
                                 color: "#336E7B",
                                highlight: "#336E7B"
                                //label: "Dashboard"
                              }
                            , {
                                value: aDatasets3,
                                 color: "#22A7F0",
                                highlight: "#22A7F0"
                                 // label: "API"
                                }

                             ]
                         }

                         var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
                         window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(barChartData, options2, { responsive: true });


                     }
                 });
             });


 [WebMethod]
        public static List<object> getPieChartData()
        {
            List<object> iData = new List<object>();

            List<string> labels = new List<string>();
            labels.Add("Batch");
            labels.Add("Dashboard");
            labels.Add("API");



            iData.Add(labels);

            List<int> lst_dataItem_1 = new List<int>();
            lst_dataItem_1.Add(10);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(8);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(6);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(4);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(2);

            iData.Add(lst_dataItem_1);

            List<int> lst_dataItem_2 = new List<int>();
            lst_dataItem_2.Add(80);
            //lst_dataItem_2.Add(365);
            //lst_dataItem_2.Add(98);

            iData.Add(lst_dataItem_2);

            List<int> lst_dataItem_3 = new List<int>();
            lst_dataItem_3.Add(10);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(8);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(6);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(4);
            //lst_dataItem_1.Add(2);

            iData.Add(lst_dataItem_3);

            return iData;
        }


<div class="card-body no-padding" align="center">
        <canvas id="pie-chart" class="chart"></canvas>
<div id="doughnutLegend"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see various issues.

In the $.ajax call, in the data attribute you send "{}" string instead of a JSON: {}.

In the getPieChartData() WebMethod you return a list of object but it shouldn't return a JSON valid string?!.

Read the documentation of http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart to check if you are using the correct attributes on your graph.